# Selenium::Remote::Driver - stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: selenium, perl

***EDIT:** a few seconds after page loads a cookies warning gets added to the page (which I didn't notice before, and of course I accepted it manually in my browser a long time ago)... which, I guess, invalidates whatever happened before that. so I just added wait after the get() and its all good now.*

`stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` error while looping over WebElements found with `find_elements()` after the first element.

---

Trying to run this simple script

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;

use Selenium::Chrome;
my $driver = Selenium::Chrome->new( binary => 'C:/path-to/chromedriver.exe' );

$driver->get( 'https://...' );

my $pdf_links = $driver->find_elements('//a[@class="file-link"]');

for my $link (@$pdf_links) {
    my $filename = $driver->find_child_element($link, "./span")->get_text();
    say $filename;
}
```

and I get this error:

```
first-file-name.pdf
Error while executing command: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=75.0.3770.90 (a6dcaf7e3ec6f70a194cc25e8149475c6590e025-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1003})
,platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64) at C:/<path>/perl/perl/site/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 403.

 at C:/<path>/perl/perl/site/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 353.
```

The `@$pdf_links` has over 160 elements, but `find_child_element()` only works on 1st iteration.

Comment: It means that either the element changed in the page, or element gets deleted, full reference in this link http://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp

Comment: yeah, sorry, I JUST find out why -- a few seconds after page loads a cookies warning gets added to the page (which I didn't notice before, and of course I accepted manually in my browser a long time ago)... which, I guess, invalidates whatever happened to before that. so I just added wait after the `get()` and its all good now.

Comment: Please post the solution as an Answer rather than an edit to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А few seconds after page loads a "cookies warning" gets added to the page (which I didn't notice before, and, of course, I accepted it manually in my browser a long time ago)... which, I guess, invalidates whatever happened before that. So, I just added a wait after the `get()` and its all good now.